# Converting C# to Python base64 encoding

Tags: python, c#, arrays, base64

I am trying to convert a function from C# to python.

My C# code:

```cs
static string Base64Encode(string plainText)
{
    char[] arr = plainText.ToCharArray();
    List<byte> code16 = new List<byte>();
    int i = 1;
    string note = "";
    foreach (char row in arr)
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            note += "0x" + row;
        }
        else if (i == 2)
        {
            note += row;
            code16.Add(Convert.ToByte(note, 16));
            note = "";
            i = 0;
        }

        i++;
    }
    return System.Convert.ToBase64String(code16.ToArray());
}
```

My Python code:

```
def Base64Ecode(plainText):
    code16 = []
    i = 1
    note = ''
    for row in plainText:
        if i == 1:
            note += '0x' + row
        elif i == 2:
            note += row
            code16.append(int(note, 16))
            note = ''
            i = 0
        i += 1
    test = ''
    for blah in code16:
        test += chr(blah)

    print(base64.b64encode(test.encode()))
```

Both `code16` values are the same but I have an issue when I try to `base64` encode the data.
C# takes a byte array but pyton takes a string and I am getting two different results.

Comment: Have you tried debugging this?  The string/characters may be encoded differently

Comment: Both arrays seem to be the same (code16) but I am stuck on converting the array into a value to pass into the b64encode in python

Comment: Hi, do you find the solution? I met the same problem,  the below answer doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`string.encode()` uses the utf-8 encoding by default, which probably creates some multi-byte chars you don't want.

Use `string.encode("latin1")` to create bytes from `00` to `FF`.

That said, there is an easier method in python to convert a Hex-String to a bytearray (or bytes object):

```
base64.b64encode(bytes.fromhex(plainText))
```

gives the same result as your function.